# Different evaluation results of python if else expression

Tags: python, if-statement, expression, evaluation

The following two expressions use if...else...

I can understand the *c2* result. But I wonder why *c1* returns a different result.

```
a = 10
c1 = 10 + a if a > 20 else -a
c2 = 10 + (a if a > 20 else -a)

print(c1, c2)
```

Output:

```
-10    0
```

Comment: The `c1` is evaluated as `c1 = (10+a) if a>20 else -a` hence output is `-10`

Comment: whenever you are unclear about a complex expression value, just check operator precedence, or simply add all brackets, even redundant ones, to ensure there is no confusion possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) issue, `+` has higher precedence than `if`, so

```
c1 = 10 + a if a > 20 else -a
```

is evaluated as

```
c1 = (10 + a) if a > 20 else -a
   = 20 if 10 > 20 else -10
   = -10       # because 10 <= 20
```

where your second statement is evaluated as written

```
c2 = 10 + (a if a > 20 else -a)
   = 10 + (10 if 10 > 20 else -10)
   = 10 + -10       # because 10 <= 20
   = 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

`c1` is equivalent to `(10 + a) if a > 20 else -a`